# how to process only the parent element if the child has the same name

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

the parent and child nodes have the same names/, so when using xslt, it is applied to both the parent and the child node, how do I make sure that only the parent is checked?

XML:

```
<data>
  <score>
    <score>111</score>
    <test>222</test>
    ...
  </score>
</data>
```

part of the xslt that was applied to xml:

```
    <xsl:if test="score != '' and score != 'null'">
        <xsl:element name="score">
            <xsl:for-each select="score">
                <xsl:element name="element">
                    <xsl:call-template name="fillElements"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
     </xsl:if>
```

result:

```
    <data>
        <score>
            <element>
                <score>111</score>
                <test>222</test>
                <score>
                    <element/>
                </score>
            </element>
        </score>
    </data>
```

expected:

```
<data>
        <score>
            <element>
                <score>111</score>
                <test>222</test>
            </element>
        </score>
    </data>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a template (not sure whether you want `match="score[score]"` instead of the version shown below):

```
  <xsl:template match="score[*]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <element>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </element>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

and let the identity transformation handle the rest.